# MVC - Unable to set field/property on entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables in my entity framework:

INATIVOS (Employees)
EMPRESAS (Companies)

When registering an employee I select a company in a @Html.DropDownListFor (List).

The registration is ok, the company is saved correctly. However, when trying to edit a registered employee shows the error "Unable to set field/property on entity" in the Companies list.

INATIVO.cs

```
public partial class INATIVOS
{
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string COD_EMPRESA { get; set; }
        public string CHAPA { get; set; }
        public string NOME { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DATA_NASC { get; set; }
        public string PLANO { get; set; }
        public short LEI { get; set; }
        public short APOSENTADO { get; set; }
        public short ESTADO_VIDA { get; set; }
        public short ISENTO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> INICIO_VIGENCIA { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FIM_VIGENCIA { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public string EMAIL { get; set; }
        public string ENDERECO { get; set; }
        public string NUMERO { get; set; }
        public string COMPLEMENTO { get; set; }
        public string BAIRRO { get; set; }
        public string CIDADE { get; set; }
        public string ESTADO { get; set; }
        public string CEP { get; set; }
        public string TELEFONE { get; set; }
        public string CELULAR { get; set; }
        public string OBSERVACAO { get; set; }

        public List<DEPENDENTES> DEPENDENTES { get; set; }
        public List<EMPRESAS> EMPRESAS { get; set; }
        public List<PLANOS_MEDICO> PLANOS_MEDICO { get; set; }
}
```

InativoController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
            INATIVOS inaModel = new INATIVOS();

            using (Entidades db = new Entidades())
            {
                if (id != null)
                {
                    inaModel = db.INATIVOS.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                inaModel.EMPRESAS = db.EMPRESAS.ToList<EMPRESAS>();
                inaModel.PLANOS_MEDICO = db.PLANOS_MEDICO.ToList<PLANOS_MEDICO>();
            }

            return View(inaModel);
}
```

Comment: System.Data.EntityException: "Unable to set the field/property EMPRESAS in the entity type RHInativo.Models.INATIVOS." in the row inaModel.EMPRESAS = db.EMPRESAS.ToList<EMPRESAS>();

Comment: The error only happens when trying to view a registered employee.

Comment: This model setup is very strange.  For one thing, navigation properties should be `virtual` and should probably be something like `IList` or `ICollection` instead of `List`.  Which may even fix your problem, though I suspect you're going to have more problems.  When you fetch an employee record from the database, why do you then immediately replace companies and medical plans with *every company and medical plan in the entire database*?

Comment: With virtual IList my datatable with all employees gives error, when I try to edit I want to load all the companies with the saved company selected.

Comment: What error does it give you?  And selecting *your entire database* into a view is generally a bad idea.  More to the point, however, is that you're losing the "selected" value because you're replacing that value with, well, every value in the entire database.  The list of selected options and the list of all possible options are two different lists.

Comment: If I remove the row inaModel.EMPRESAS = db.EMPRESAS.ToList <COMPANIES> (); gives the error that the value can't be null in the View in @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.COD_EMPRESA, new SelectList(Model.EMPRESAS, "CODIGO", "DESCRICAO"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are navigation properties:

```
public List<DEPENDENTES> DEPENDENTES { get; set; }
public List<EMPRESAS> EMPRESAS { get; set; }
public List<PLANOS_MEDICO> PLANOS_MEDICO { get; set; }
```

Then (1) they need to be `virtual` and (2) they need to be something like `IList` or `ICollection`:

```
public virtual ICollection<DEPENDENTES> DEPENDENTES { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<EMPRESAS> EMPRESAS { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<PLANOS_MEDICO> PLANOS_MEDICO { get; set; }
```

---

Though, as an aside, what you're doing here is *very strange*:

```
inaModel.EMPRESAS = db.EMPRESAS.ToList<EMPRESAS>();
inaModel.PLANOS_MEDICO = db.PLANOS_MEDICO.ToList<PLANOS_MEDICO>();
```

Essentially what you have in the database is, for a given Employee (`INATIVOS`) there are relationships to *specific* Companies (`EMPRESAS`) and *specific* Medical Plans (`PLANOS_MEDICO`).  But you're ignoring whatever is in that data and replacing it with *all companies and all medical plans in the entire database*.

So every time you use this controller action to fetch an existing employee record, it's going to look like that employee has every company and every medical plan.  Even though that's not what's in the database.  I *strongly* suspect that's not what you want.

---

**UPDATE:**  Based on comments on this answer, it sounds like those aren't navigation properties.  They're not even properties of the model at all.  They're just lists of data needed for the view to populate (presumably) `<select>` elements.

If they're not part of the data model then remove them from the model.  Instead, consider using a view model.  For example:

```
public class InativosViewModel
{
    public INATIVOS Inativos { get; set; }
    public List<EMPRESAS> EMPRESAS { get; set; }
    public List<PLANOS_MEDICO> PLANOS_MEDICO { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller return an instance of the view model, which is a composite object of the model and the data needed for the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    InativosViewModel result = new InativosViewModel();

    using (Entidades db = new Entidades())
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            result.Inativos = db.INATIVOS.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        result.EMPRESAS = db.EMPRESAS.ToList<EMPRESAS>();
        result.PLANOS_MEDICO = db.PLANOS_MEDICO.ToList<PLANOS_MEDICO>();
    }

    return View(result);
}
```

And of course change the model binding in the view itself to now expect and use an instance of `InativosViewModel`.  The resulting POST action can still accept an instance of `INATIVOS` if it needs to, or it can accept an instance of `InativosViewModel` just as well.  That all depends on what the form structure is and what's being posted to that action.

**Alternatively**, if you want to keep using the `INATIVOS` model then still remove those lists from it but use something like `ViewBag` to send them to the view.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    INATIVOS inaModel = new INATIVOS();

    using (Entidades db = new Entidades())
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            inaModel = db.INATIVOS.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        ViewBag.Empresas = db.EMPRESAS.ToList<EMPRESAS>();
        ViewBag.PlanosMedico = db.PLANOS_MEDICO.ToList<PLANOS_MEDICO>();
    }

    return View(inaModel);
}
```

Then in your view you would populate the `<select>` elements from there:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => Model.COD_EMPRESA,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Empresas, "CODIGO", "DESCRICAO"),
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"
})
```

Comment: When ActionResult Index(int? id) receives an id, what would be the correct way to recover the list of companies with the saved company selected?

Comment: @AndersonCosta: When you say "the saved company" what data in the model are you referring to?  You have a *list* of companies, not one company.  In general you might have a view model which has the model being edited and the data for the view.  In this case the complete list of all companies from which to choose is data for the view, so it would be a `List<EMPRESAS>` on the view model.  If there should be only *one* "saved company" then that needs to be an `EMPRESAS` property on the model.

Comment: A saved company is a code that corresponds to a value of the list of companies.

Comment: @AndersonCosta: Once again, which actual value on the model are you referring to?

Comment: COD_EMPRESA refers to a value of List List<EMPRESAS> EMPRESAS. This is the saved value. @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.COD_EMPRESA, new SelectList(Model.EMPRESAS, "CODIGO", "DESCRICAO"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: @AndersonCosta: So then these `List<T>` properties aren't meant to be part of the data model at all?  They shouldn't be on the model then.  Either use a view model that's a composite of the model and the data needed for the view or use something like `ViewData` or `ViewBag` for the data that isn't part of the model.  (The lists from the database to populate the `<select>` elements.)

Comment: @AndersonCosta: I've updated the answer to show some examples.

Comment: Thank you, David! The alternative solution worked fine.